# How to get original rendition of an image uploaded in DAM using AbstractImageServlet?

Tags: aem

We have written a custom servlet by extending the AbstractImageServlet and registered it against a custom selector and we are overriding the createLayer method . Returning a layer either from the image or after getting the layer from original rendition of the image does not return the original image and height of the image

```
Image img=new Image(imageContext.resource);
Layer layer=img.getLayer(true, true, true);
return layer;
```

or

```
Resource imgResource = imageContext.request.getResourceResolver()
                .getResource(imagePath);
        Layer layer=imgResource.getLayer(true, true, true);
        return layer;
```

where imagePath is the path of original rendition of the image

The size of the original rendition of image in DAM is 2048 × 1100 and 220 KB

but the size of the image returned by the servlet after getting the layer from the original rendition is 1280*687 and 292 KB

The getLayer method of com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.Image class does not return the original rendition's exact same size.

How can we get the original image's natural size a custom servlet extending the AbstractImageServlet ?

Answer (score 1):

We will face the above situation, when the uploaded image has a width more than 1280px. AbstractImageServlet.ImageContext has a layer of max width 1280px. As you have uploaded an image of width 2048px, it's resized. 
If you try an image having width less then 1280px, it will not be resized.

However, you have to update the one service in system configurations and one DAM asset workflow step to make it work.

Configuration: Day CQ DAM Buffered Image Cache
Property: Max Dimension "2048x2048"

Workflow Step: DAM Update Asset: Process Thumbnails:
Web Enabled Image: Width- 2048 and height- 2048.

for more details please look into below links:

https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/remove-web-rendition-dimension-limit.html

https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/cqbufferedimagecache-consumes-heap-during-asset-uploads.html

Answer (score 0):

There is also another option of getting layer for original rendition - when you have image resource you can do next thing:

```
Asset asset = imageResource.adaptTo(Asset.class);
Rendition original = asset.getOriginal();
Layer layer = new Layer(original.getStream());
```

Comment: Tried this; not getting the exact same dimensions and size as the original rendition.

Comment: @user2776643 can you set a breakpoint on the line next after Layer creation and debug, what size is of the layer? It can be, that during next steps of request processing, servlet compresses the image.

Comment: height and width is the same as the original rendition; but the image size in KBs is not the same. The size is more than the oroginal rendition's size. Any idea why it is not the same and how can we make it the same as original rendition's size?

Comment: @user2776643 can you post there original size and size of created layer? Because if size is several KBs - then it can be just additional metadata written by AEM.